# Find what happens when you click an HTML button

Tags: javascript, html

For example, you have this script that adds an event listener to a button like this:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
});
```

How would I see that code in a website, so I can execute the code from the console?

Comment: The Inspector / Elements tab in the dev tools should be able to show bound listeners.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, where would i find that? I am on the button element, but I don't see anything.

Comment: [Examine Event Listeners](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners).

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome, you can open developer tools, select the element, then select the 'Event Listeners' tab:

[image]

Which will show you the event listeners bound to the element:

[image]

Comment: How would I find the real function to do it? It takes me to the source, which I think is obfuscated.

Comment: @Phenomenon It's because SO minified their JS. On a normal site, if the JS isn't minified, you'll be able to see it fine.

Answer (score 0):

You want to trigger the event from the console. But that is not possible. However, you can call an external function in the second parameter of the EventListener. This function is then in the global scope. You can then trigger the action in the console with the function name that would otherwise be triggered via the click.

`makeAction();`

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  makeAction();
});

function makeAction() {
  console.log('triggered')
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">click</buton>
<div id="demo"></div>
```